# Compare dates of an array using moment or dayjs library in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, validation, momentjs, dayjs

I need to compare the date values of an array.
I will always get two dates values in array. If date range is not in between 5 years need to display error message.

```
filterAry = [
  {type: 'date', name: 'fromDate',  value:['15/02/2017']},
  {type: 'date', name: 'toDate',  value:['15/02/2023']},
  {type: 'string', name: 'code',  value:'new role'}
];
```

I am trying moment to get the difference between two dates also filtering the array values based on type='date' first.

```
filterAry.forEach(item => {
    if (item.type === 'date') {
        if(item.name === 'fromDate'){
                date1 = moment(item.value[0],'DD/MM/YYYY')
         }
         else{
                date2 = moment(item.value[0],'DD/MM/YYYY');
         }
         if(date1 && date2){
                dateVal3 = date2.diff(date1, 'years');
         }
}
```

My code is not working and also I am not sure how to write the code without hard coded values.I need difference of the to and from dates and if it is greater than 5 years should display error message. Kindly help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem begin from the fact that that you're doing assignments and comparing values inside the foreach, try to deconstruct it a bit and use maybe something like Array.filter to filter down the initial array and map to get the values extracted like this:

```js
  const filterAry = [
    { type: 'date', name: 'fromDate',  value:['15/02/2017'] },
    { type: 'date', name: 'toDate',  value:['15/02/2023'] },
    { type: 'string', name: 'code',  value:'new role' }
  ]
  // find the elements that contains dates
  const dates = filterAry.filter((el) => el.type === 'date')
  
  // store them as regular values instead of arrays with 1 cell
  const [dateStart, dateEnd] = dates.map((el) => moment(el.value[0], 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
  // calculate year diff
  const yearDiff = moment(dateEnd).diff(dateStart, 'years')

  console.log(yearDiff) // 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*Array.prototype.reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop over the values in the array to find the to and from dates, then test them. You can also use [*Array.prototype.some*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), but it needs to be wrapped in a function to store interim results so is more-or-less the same as *reduce* anyway.

However, for large arrays *some* may have performance advantages as it can exit as soon as it's found *toDate* and *fromDate*. The below *reduce* example optimised a bit so that if the result *true* or *false* has already been calculated it just skips to the next value, but it will still iterate over all elements in the array.

```js
// Helpers
// Parse dd/mm/yyyy format timestamp
function parseDMY(s) {
  let [D,M,Y] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Y, M-1, D);
}

// Add years to a date
function addYears(years, date = new Date()) {
  let d = new Date(date);
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 5);
  // If date was 29 Feb, make d 28 Feb not 1 Mar 
  if (d.getDate() != date.getDate()) {
    d.setDate(0)
  }
  return d;
}

// Sample data
let arr = [
  {type: 'date', name: 'fromDate',  value:['15/02/2017']},
  {type: 'date', name: 'toDate',  value:['15/02/2023']},
  {type: 'string', name: 'code',  value:'new role'}
];

// Test if toDate and fromDate are within 5 years
// result is true if they're within 5 years
let result = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (acc !== true && acc !== false) {
    if (obj.type = 'date') {
      acc[obj.name] = parseDMY(obj.value[0]);
    }
    if (acc.fromDate && acc.toDate) {
      acc = acc.toDate < addYears(5, acc.fromDate);
    }
  }
  return acc;  
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result); // false
```

The above has no error handling or exception management, that should be added.